# Partial fractions for a fraction with n-terms in the denominator

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, partial-fractions

I was working doing some integrals for my project and i get stuck in how they use the partial fraction to obtain the following

$$
\dfrac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)\cdots (x+n)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{c_k}{x+k}
$$
where $c_k=\dfrac{\pi^{-k}}{k}$.

Can anyone help me with this? Or give me some ideas in how to obtain it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: ? That's not what I get when I work out the partial fraction ....

Comment: You mean the answer is not correct? In this case what will be the answer?

Comment: I doubt there can be ever a π in the coefficients. This would probably imply π is rational, or at least algebraic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression for $c_k$ is:

$$c_k=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{1\leq i\leq n,\,i\ne k}(i-k)}$$

This can be obtained most easily from the so-called "cover up method" for partial fractions.

To see all the steps:

$$\frac{1}{(x+1)\cdots(x+n)} = \frac{c_1}{x+1}+\cdots+\frac{c_n}{x+n}$$

Multiply both sides by the denominator on the left:

$$1 = \sum_{k=1}^n \left(c_k\prod_{1\leq i\leq n,\,i\ne k}(x+i)\right)$$

Setting $x=-k$, every term on the right except for the $k$th term becomes $0$, so we have:

$$1=c_k\prod_{1\leq i\leq n,\,i\ne k}(-k+i)$$

This leads directly to our solution.

Comment: You can also write this as $$\frac{(-1)^{k+1} }{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$$

Comment: Ok, but how you obtain this? I get lost now with the two answers

Comment: $$ \prod_{1\le i \le n, \; i \ne k} (i-k) = \left(\prod_{1 \le i \le k-1} (i-k)\right) \left(\prod_{k+1 \le i \le n} (i-k)\right)$$
The first gives you the $(-1)^{k+1}(k-1)!$.  The second, $(n-k)!$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael ok thank you so much, then $c_k=\dfrac{1}{(-1)^{k+1} (k-1)! (n-k)!}$

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if the $(-1)^{k+1}$ factor is in the numerator or the denominator.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs there is something wrong now i'm sure that $c_k$ must equal to $\dfrac{\pi^{-k}}{k}$

Comment: Try it for $n=2$

Comment: @GTonyJacobs yes i'm sorry it is correct, i find it and your answer is correct it works. Thank you so much